# Can't get two switchclasses to work defaults back after one or two clicks

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tumblr

Okay so I'm making a theme for tumblr. I'm using isotope for layout options. What I want is for there to be two choices -- one column with wide posts (filling the entire div the posts will be in), and the other is a masonry layout with (i think i set) 3 columns.
I also am using isotope to make filters so that people can narrow down what they see by post type.

*note: this is a very basic skeleton copy of the theme, just so i can figure out the javascript/jquery first without too much clutter in my way. i will be adding other divs and sections in once i figure this out, making sure to leave this alone and work around it all.
below is a copy of the html for the page thus far. i have been creating it in dreamweaver and then copy pasting it into tumblr, where the {tags} are rendered into actual posts. to see this page as it is intended, go to http://drmstx-testing.tumblr.com and i have only 2 or 3 posts in there, but it's enough to give you the idea.

what im frustrated with is that clicking on the links for grid or one column works maybe once and then nothing happens, OR the only thing that is changing is the layout, not the css that makes the size of the posts bigger and smaller as i change layouts. also, i want it to look smooth, for example at one point i got it kind of working with some glitches and all the content would minimize to nothing and then flash/cut right to the correct layout. i want people to see the post move to its spot and just shrink or grow a little, that's all.
if you can help me with this, i know this is probably confusing especially with the tumblr code tags in there. id take them out, but i think that the way tumblr renders it is actually changing how it behaves so i kind of need it in there ... if you need clarification, let me know.

to make this a little easier, look for these classes and parts of the code -- .box  .grid  .onecolumn || end of css, the javascript section, and the beginning of the body

```
    <style type="text/css">

        /**** Isotope filtering ****/

        .isotope-item {
          z-index: 2;
        }

        .isotope-hidden.isotope-item {
          pointer-events: none;
          z-index: 1;
        }

        .isotope,
        .isotope .isotope-item {
          /* change duration value to whatever you like */
          -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
             -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
                  transition-duration: 0.8s;
        }

        .isotope {
          -webkit-transition-property: height, width;
             -moz-transition-property: height, width;
                  transition-property: height, width;
        }

        .isotope .isotope-item {
          -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;
             -moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, opacity;
                  transition-property:         transform, opacity;
        }

        /*==============================*/
        .post {
            transition: all 1st ease-in-out;
            -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
            -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
            transition-duration: 0.8s;
        }
        .post img {width: 100%;}

        .grid {
            width: 33%;
            min-width: 350px;
            max-width: 475px;
        }

        .onecolumn {
            width: 100%;
        }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://isotope.metafizzy.co/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var $container = $('#content');
            $container.isotope({
                filter: '*',
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false,
                }
            });

            $('#nav #sort a').click(function(){
                var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                $container.isotope({
                    filter: selector,
                    animationOptions: {
                        duration: 750,
                        easing: 'linear',
                        queue: false,
                    }
                });
            return false;
            });

            $('#nav #layout a').click(function(){
                var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
                $container.isotope({
                    layoutMode: selector,
                    animationOptions: {
                        duration: 750,
                        easing: 'linear',
                        queue: false,
                    }

                });
            return false;
            });
        });
            function grid(){
                $(".post").switchClass( "onecolumn", "grid", 400, "easeInOut" );
            };

            function onecol(){
                $(".post").switchClass( "grid", "onecolumn", 400, "easeInOut" );
            };

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="sort">
            <h3>Filter</h3>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" data-filter="*">all</a></li>
                <li><a href="" data-filter=".text">text</a></li>
                <li><a href="" data-filter=".photopost">photo</a></li>
                <li><a href="" data-filter=".quote">quote</a></li>
                <li><a href="" data-filter=".link">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="" data-filter=".chat">chat</a></li>
                <li><a href="" data-filter=".video">video</a></li>
                <li><a href="" data-filter=".audio">audio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="layout">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" onclick="onecol()" data-filter="straightDown">Single Column</a></li>
                <li><a href="" onclick="grid()" data-filter="masonry">Grid</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content" class="isotope">
        {block:Posts}
            <article>
                <!--Unique code for each post type-->
                {block:Text}
                    <div class="post text grid">
                        {block:Title}
                            <h1 class="title"><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h1>
                        {/block:Title}
                        {Body}
                    </div>
                {/block:Text}

                {block:Photo}
                    <div class="post photo grid">
                        {LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />{LinkCloseTag}
                        {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
                    </div>
                {/block:Photo}

                {block:Photoset}
                    <div class="post photoset grid">
                        {Photoset-500}
                        {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
                    </div>
                {/block:Photoset}

                {block:Panorama}
                    <div class="post panorama grid">
                        {LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-Panorama}" alt="{PhotoAlt}" />{LinkCloseTag}
                        {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
                    </div>
                {/block:Panorama}

                {block:Quote}
                    <div class="post quote grid">
                        <blockquote>{Quote}</blockquote>
                        {block:Source}<cite> {Source} </cite>{/block:Source}
                    </div>
                {/block:Quote}

                {block:Link}
                    <div class="post link grid" data-category="link">
                        <h1 class="title"><a href="{URL}">{Name}</a></h1>
                        {block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}
                    </div>
                {/block:Link}

                {block:Chat}
                    <div class="post chat grid" data-category="chat">
                        <ul>
                            {block:Lines}<li class="{Alt}">{block:Label}<span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label}<p> {Line} </p></li>{/block:Lines}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                {/block:Chat}

                {block:Audio}
                    <div class="post audio grid" data-category="audio">
                        {block:TrackName}<h1 class="title"><a href="{Permalink}">{TrackName}</a></h1>{/block:TrackName}
                        {block:AlbumArt}<img src="{AlbumArtURL}" width="500" height="500"/>{/block:AlbumArt}
                        <div class="player post">{AudioPlayerBlack}</div>
                        {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
                    </div>
                {/block:Audio}

                {block:Video}
                    <div class="post video grid" data-category="video">
                        <div class="video-player">{Video-500}</div>
                        {block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}
                    </div>
                {/block:Video}

                {block:Answer}
                    <div class="post answer grid" data-category="answer">
                        <h1 class="title">{Question}</h1>
                        <div class="user">
                            <img src="{AskerPortraitURL-96}"/>
                            <p>{Asker}</p>
                        </div>
                        {Answer}
                    </div>
                {/block:Answer}
            </article>
        {/block:Posts}
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: anybody?? please i really can't figure this out!